# Search and Replace in specific column of csv with python

Tags: python, csv, excel

I created a program that search and replaces over an entire csv file but I need to make so it is column specific. Is there a way to only search via a column. Here is my code, I am pretty new to python so I apologize if this is an easy fix.

```
import csv

ifile = open('testbook.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='\t')
ofile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')

findL = ['Australia', 'Mexico', 'United States', 'hob']
replaceL = ['Kangaroo', 'Spider Monkey', 'Eagle', 'Test']

rep = dict(zip(findL, replaceL))

def findReplace(find, replace):
    s = ifile.read()
    for item, replacement in zip(findL, replaceL):
        s = s.replace(item, replacement)
    ofile.write(s)

for item in findL:
    findReplace(item, rep[item])

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by using `pandas`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Austria', 'Germany', 'hob', 'Australia'],
        ['Spain', 'France', 'Italy', 'Mexico']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B','C','D'])

# Values to find and their replacements
findL = ['Australia', 'Mexico', 'United States', 'hob']
replaceL = ['Kangaroo', 'Spider Monkey', 'Eagle', 'Test']

# Select column (can be A,B,C,D)
col = 'C';

# Find and replace values in the selected column
df[col] = df[col].replace(findL, replaceL)
```

Comment: Okay cool that would work, is there a way I import a csv or excel as the data?

Comment: yes, you can use **pandas.read_csv()** :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenPyxl , you can use this line :

```
for col_cells in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
```

Just enough to fix the number of rows or columns, you could fix one or both